# How to use Azure AD authentication with Redis Cache

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-redis-cache

I have created an MVC application with Azure AD configured. So all the Authentication setup is automated.

But I want to store users session in Azure Redis Cache. As I will be using multiple instances

I know how to setup redis cache in azure. But from where I can add Session in cache ?

As I have only got this code

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store the session in redis:

[ASP.NET Session State Provider for Azure Redis Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-aspnet-session-state-provider)

> Once these steps are performed, your application is configured to use the Redis Cache Session State Provider. When you use session state in your application, it is stored in an Azure Redis Cache instance.

If you want to use redis for stuff other than session cache:

[How to create a Web App with Redis Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-web-app-howto)

Comment: But here how can we check if the data is there in the session or not ? Or it will happen through the configurations done in the config file ?

Comment: You use the session state as you normally would. See the quote in the answer.